# GMM in MATLAB gives different results for the same file

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics, gaussian

I constructed a Gaussian Mixture Model in Matlab with a dataset:

```
model = gmdistribution.fit(data,M,'Replicates',5);
```

with `M = 3` Gaussian components. I tested new data with:

```
[P, l] = posterior(model,new_data);
```

I ran the program several times and didn't get the same result. Each run produces different log-likelihood values. I use the log-likelihood to make decisions, and this value for the same data (`new_data`) differs for each run. What does it depend on? How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, assuming that you're using a newish `version` of Matlab, the [`gmdistribution.fit`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.fit.html) documentation  indicates that the `fit` method is deprecated and that [`fitgmdist`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/fitgmdist.html) should be used. See [`here`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution-class.html#bty1gzy-1) for an example.

Second, the documentation for `gmdistribution.fit` indicates that if the `'Replicates'` option is larger than 1, the `'randSample'` start method will be used to produce the initial parameters. This may be the cause (or at least one of the causes) of your observed variability.

Finally, you can also try using [`rng`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) before calling `gmdistribution.fit` to set the seed of the global random number stream (assuming the function doesn't use it's own stream internally). Alternatively, you can try specifying an [`'Options'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.fit.html#zmw57dd0e207301) parameter via [`statset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/statset.html):

```
seed = 1;
s = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',seed);
opts = statset('Streams',s);
model = gmdistribution.fit(data,M,'Replicates',5,'Options',opts);
```

I can't test this fully myself – see the [`gmdistribution`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution-class.html) class documentation for further details.